# Eclipse: Can You Add A Command To The Context Menu

Tags: eclipse, contextmenu

I'm new to Eclipse.   Is it possible to add a command to the context menu ( right click in an editor ) without writing a plugin?   I don't want to make a code contribution to Eclipse, just put a frequently used command there, in my own copy, for my convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to write a plugin to contribute a new context menu.

Comment: I don't want to make a code contribution to Eclipse, just put a frequently used command there, in my own copy, for my convenience.

Comment: Writing a plugin doesn't mean making a code contribution to Eclipse. You can write a plugin just for yourself, share it with your friends, host on GitHub, sell it, whatever.

Answer (score -1):

The context menu cannot be changed unless you build your own version of Eclipse

Comment: Because you do not have to build your own version of Eclipse to extend it. Eclipse has a number of extension points which you can leverage in a plugin to add a context menu, a new wizard, etc. A plugin can even have its own extension points, etc.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik That was exactly the point I was getting at, surely not as explicit as you did, but still..